# Where can I find information about vulkan instance layers and extensions?

Tags: vulkan

I figured they would be listed in the official documentation here

https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/VkInstanceCreateInfo.html

but clicking on the layers link does nothing and there's nothing on extensions either

I found a snippet here describing the concept along with some code here

http://gpuopen.com/using-the-vulkan-validation-layers/

but it must be outdated since there is no such thing as "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation" in my vulkan header (1.0.21.1) or anything starting with "VK_LAYER" for that matter.

I think I got the SDK hooked up correctly, I got the instance running and I can check out compatible hardware and stuff but I just need some more solid documentation to go along with my progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layers are documented in [Lunar Xchange](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/signin). The SDK ones are open source, and sometimes it is beneficial to look in the source or documentation provided along it — which is on GitHub: [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/tree/master/layers)
.

WSI extensions are documented along the core Vulkan in the appropriate [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html) (accessible from the [registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/#repo-docs)).

Other extensions are source only (AFAIK) for now as linked in the [registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/#repo-docs). I would not be surprised if some external party hosted them — e.g. the [Lunar Xchange](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/signin) has them compiled at least for the `VK_EXT_debug_report` and `VK_EXT_debug_marker` extension.

UPDATE:

---

The extensions are not so complex yet. For immediate needs it suffices to open the appropriate GitHub branch and click "compare" to see the relevant parts (in harder to read source form).

Somewhat related are the SPIR-V extensions which are properly accessible in the [SPIR-V registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/spir-v/#extensions).

---

`KHR_vulkan_glsl` is text only and available [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/misc/GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl.txt) (also accessible from the [registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/#repo-docs)). (Being exception overall — e.g. it does not need to be enabled.)

`VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` is a thing. It is a meta-layer. It enables all the other validation layers and do so in proper order.

Layers have nothing in the C header, because they cannot introduce new functionality. They can only be enumerated and enabled, with the appropriate functions. `VK_LAYER_` is indeed the proper prefix and what `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` should return to you.